# How to change value on Laravel 5 from function?

Tags: function, laravel-5, google-maps-api-3, laravel-blade, htmlcollection

i wanna ask about Laravel HTML Collective.
So i have form with location.
[image: Location Form Edit]

So this picture, is come from edit page. The latitude and longitude is get from database. Now i will change that value after search place.[image: Search new place]

and i already make google maps api function to get the value. but now i confuse how to change the input form.
[image]

so, here's my function code.

```
function codeAddress(address) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {
      var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();

      console.log('lat:' + lat + ', lng:' + lng);

      if (marker) { marker.setMap(null); }

      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
          lat: lat,
          lng: lng
        },
        map: map,
        icon : '{{ url('/images/marker.png') }}'
      });

      map.setCenter( new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng) );
    } else {
      console.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });

}
```

and here's my page edit.blade code

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
          {{ Form::label('longitude', 'Longitude') }}              
          {{ Form::number(
            'longitude',
            ( isset($db) ) ? $db->longitude : null,
            array(
              'class' => 'form-control'
            )
          ) }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
          {{ Form::label('latitude', 'Latitude') }}                          
          {{ Form::number(
            'latitude',
            ( isset($db) ) ? $db->latitude : null,
            array(
              'class' => 'form-control'
            )
          ) }}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need make some changes, in `Laravel` blade

```
   {{ Form::number('latitude',( isset($db) ) ? $db->latitude : null,
            array(
              'class' => 'form-control'
              'id'=>'latitude' // put this line 
            )
      )
   }}

   {{ Form::number('longitude',( isset($db) ) ? $db->longitude : null,
            array(
              'class' => 'form-control'
              'id'=>'longitude' // put this line 
            )
      )
    }}
```

Make some `JS` changes also, this will change latitude , longitude when call `codeAddress(address)`.

```
 map.setCenter( new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng) );
 $("#longitude").value(lng);
 $("#latitude").value(lat);
```